# Show/Hide fields not working for Condition Fields on node display

Tags: entities

I have [Conditional fields](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) installed, with a checkbox as the dependency which shows two textareas when checked. The issue is when viewing the content type, the checkbox is NOT checked and the text areas still show up. I have checked in `Manage Dependencies` and the dependants are required and visible when checkbox field is checked.

Is there another place to adjust these settings, if so where would I look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quirk of the module, per the [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1704126) on the view context:

> The "Value", "Filled" and "Empty" conditions are special: they are the
>   only conditions that have ANY effect on form validation and content
>   view.

If you want to show/hide fields with the module during content display, you'll need to set the **Condition** to *Value* and the according value for your checkbox.